# Logstash metrics plugin: What does events.rate_5m mean?

Tags: logstash

This is should be a fairly easy question for Logstash veterans.

When I use the metrics plugin, what does events.rate_5m mean?

1. Does it mean:  Number of events per second in a 5 minute window?
2. Does it mean:  Number of events every 5 minutes?

Also, what's the difference between using this over timer.rate_5m?

The documentation isn't very clear and I have problems understanding it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logstash uses the [Metriks](https://github.com/eric/metriks) library to generate the metrics.

According to that site:

> A meter that measures the mean throughput and the one-, five-, and fifteen-minute exponentially-weighted moving average throughputs.

and

> A timer measures the average time as well as throughput metrics via a meter.

A `meter` counts events and a `timer` is used to look at durations (you have to pass a name and a value into a timer).

To answer your specific question, the `rate_5m` is the per second rate over the last 5 minute sliding window.